# Is there a way to tie code to multiple GAS using clasp for testing?

Tags: google-apps-script, clasp

I work on a lot of google scripts that are tied to different people's google sheets. Recently I've been trying to shift to using Clasp and VS Code to make it easier to keep a history and add to Github. This is great as it helps streamline my process however, most of the GAS I am working are tied to sheets that are used for someone else's business, which means if I push buggy code, I can mess up their business.

I don't want to push directly to the "production script" without testing the code first using the dummy sheet I built along with my dummy calendar and dummy email. This means that I first want to push the code to my "dummy script", test it, then, when ready, push the code to the "production sheet.

Is there a way to do this? I have looked, but no one seems to have a similar need to my own as most people use clasp to push scripts, then deploy them after testing. My need is different since, when I push the code, it will be effective immediately and does not deploy. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try modifying clasp.json file every time you want to switch over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires some manual manipulation before pushing, but one approach that at least allows you to maintain a single copy of the code is as follows:

Clasp always pushes to the script identified by the script id in the file `.clasp.json` ([how to find a project's script id](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp#clone_an_existing_project)).  This file usually contains exactly one key/value pair:

```
{
    "scriptId": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678910",
}
```

By experimentation, I've discovered that additional key/value pairs can be included, and clasp will ignore them.  It only pushes to the script identified by `scriptId`.  Therefore, I keep a list of all projects I might want to push to, in `.clasp.json`, something like this:

```
{
    "scriptId": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678910",
    "production": "987654321zxywvutrsqpomnlkjifghedcba",
    "development": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz12345678910"
}
```

As currently shown, `clasp push` will push to the development copy.  If you want to push to production, copy and paste the production id value into the top `scriptId` line and then `clasp push`.

It's not completely automatic but at least it keeps all the script id's in one place.  You could also write a short command line script that performs the copy/paste manipulation automatically and pushes to the desired branch.

Comment: This is a fantastic tip. Thank you for responding! I was working on implementing something similar but I got annoyed by having to copy and paste from a separate text file. keeping it in the same file should reduce at least a bit of the load.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! If you feel it sufficiently answers the question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have now. Sorry, still a bit new at submitting to Stack. I'm used to just reading and moving on. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by creating a local NodeJS project with https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-clasp2
It automatically pushes the code to the GAS projects with only one configuration file, using Clasp in the background.